# the memory address of object between python and c++ are not identical

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to print the memory address of the same object in both c++ and python with pybind11, but I found the returned memory address from both are not identical.

c++ side

```
class Example {
  public:
    Example() {std::cout << "constuctor" << this << std::endl;}
    ~Example() {std::cout << "destructor " << this << std::endl;}
};

class ABC {
  public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Example> get_example() {
      // std::shared_ptr<Example> ptr = std::make_shared<Example>();
      std::unique_ptr<Example> ptr = std::make_unique<Example>();
      return ptr;
    }
};

void init_example(py::module & m) {
    py::class_<ABC>(m, "ABC")
    .def_static("get_example", &ABC::get_example);
}
```

python side

```
example = my_module.ABC.get_example()
print (example)
```

the output

```
constuctor0x234cd80
<Example object at 0x7f5493c37928>
destructor 0x234cd80
```

the memory address from c++ is 0x234cd80, but python is 0x7f5493c37928

any idea?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're attempting to print out.  You are printing out `this` in the C++ code, but in actually in `get_example`, you're creating a `std::unique_ptr`, and its address is not going to be the same as `this`.  [See this example](https://www.ideone.com/5me0zz).  Issue seems to have nothing to do with Python.

Comment: my mistake. I thought the address of `std::unique_ptr` is the same as the address of the object it points to.

Comment: But how to print out the memory address o the object in python?

Comment: You need to call the `get()` function, by whatever means Python gives you.

Answer (score 2):

pybind11 creates a Python object which has a reference to C++ object. So addresses of Python pybind11 wrapper and C++ object are different.

The address in default pybind11 str object representation is the address of python object, not of underlying C++ object or it's smart pointer.

If you need to know address of C++ object add a method to you binding code as @PaulMcKenzie suggested.

*C++:*

```
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example_module, m){
  m.def("add", add);

  py::class_<Example>(m,"Foo")
      .def(py::init())
      .def("get_raw_address",[](Example& foo){ return reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&foo);});

}
```

*Python:*

```py
example = Example()
print(example)
print("C++ address: %x" % example.get_raw_address())
```

*Output:*

```
constuctor 0x10eff20
<example_module.Foo object at 0x7f51c71d4298>
C++ address: 10eff20
destructor 0x10eff20
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Python aspect of this question, but focusing on the C++ portion, you are not printing out the correct information.

The `std::unique_ptr` has a different address than the `Example` instance that is created, thus the values will be different.  If you want to print the address of the item that the `unique_ptr` is addressing, you need to call the `get()` function.

Here is a full example showing the differences:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Example {
  public:
    Example() {std::cout << "constuctor " << this << std::endl;}
    ~Example() {std::cout << "destructor " << this << std::endl;}
};

class ABC {
  public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Example> get_example() 
    {
      std::unique_ptr<Example> ptr = std::make_unique<Example>();
      return ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Example> p = ABC::get_example();
    std::cout << "The unique_ptr address is: " << &p << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The get() function returns: " << p.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
constuctor 0x555a68bd7c20
The unique_ptr address is: 0x7ffd9fa6c120
The get() function returns: 0x555a68bd7c20
destructor 0x555a68bd7c20
```

So you need to adjust your Python code to print the return value of `get()`.

Comment: I made some changes but the returned memory addresses are still not identical.  `unique_ptr_address=0x7ffcc78cda70`, `python_side_address= 0x7ff4c80ab8f0`

Comment: _"So you need to adjust your Python code to print the return value of get()."_ Or adjust the C++ code, rather?